# How to determine a bitset's length without numbers at C++

Tags: c++, bitset

Is there any way to do something like this in C++:

```
int a;
bitset<a>;
```

Comment: What do you mean more precisely?

Comment: In fact i accidently submitted it when it wasn't finished. I supposed to mean can i make something like bitset<a>; when a is an int

Comment: @user6568979 You can [edit] your question to fix it.

Comment: @user6568979 But no, you cannot do that. Template arguments need to be compile time constants.

Comment: What are you wanting to have it do?

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible, since `std::bitset<>` expects a constant bitsize value, that can be resolved at compile time.

What you can do though is providing a `const` value:

```
   const int a = 42;
// ^^^^^
   bitset<a>;
```

---

As mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38283278/1413395), there's not really a *dynamically sized bitset* provided from the current c++ standard (The `std::vector<bool>` specialization has serious drawbacks regarding usage in standard algorithms).

Comment: Thank you !! I was searching for the 'constant' thanks!